# website displaying directory instead of index

Tags: apache

So I set up LAMP on a vps and in apache2/sites-available I create a file name my.domain.conf, I set the documentroot to /var/www/my.domain.com/public_html and do a2ensite and restart apache and I placed index.html into the public_html folder. But when I visit my site I just get a directory listing, if I place index.html into /var/www/html/ it works, so the document root change isnt working. Any ideas on what I may have missed?

Here is my.domain.conf

```
ServerAdmin blah@blah
ServerName my.domain.com
ServerAlias www.my.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/my.domain.com/public_html
```

Also www.my.domain.com doesnt resolve. But my.domain.com does

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify the VirtualHost tags :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my.domain.com/public_html
    ServerName my.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I do have that, i put the contents of my.domain.conf in the original post.

Comment: Thx for adding it. If www.my.domain.com doesn't resolve you may have forgot adding a DNS rule.

Comment: I think I have the proper DNS rules, my.domain.com does resolve, but www.my.domain.name doesn't.

Comment: And did you put the `<VirtualHost>` tags ? Without it it will conflict your default conf I think.